# Ajax submit validations do nothing after success response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdo

I want to submit form after validations of submit button. After validations corrected and completed error and warnings disappear but this script do nothing. I clicked submit button its just not responding and not inserting any data into database.

*By the way I showed every inputs validations in each induvidual div elements so I don't want to break this style too.*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){       
        $('#submit').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();         
            var fullname = $("#fullname").val();
            var username = $("#username").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();            
            $.ajax({
                url: 'registercontrol.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {fullname:fullname},
                success:function(response){                 
                    $("#vfullname").html(response);                 
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: 'registercontrol.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {username:username},
                success:function(response){                 
                    $("#vusername").html(response);                 
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: 'registercontrol.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {email:email},
                success:function(response){                 
                    $("#vemail").html(response);                    
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: 'registercontrol.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {password:password},
                success:function(response){                 
                    $("#vpassword").html(response);                 
                }
            });                     
        });
    });
</script>
```

registercontrol.php

```
<?php

require('../includes/config.php');

if(isset($_POST['fullname'])){
    //fullname validation
    $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];

    if (empty($_POST['fullname'])) {
        $warningfn = "Please fill this field";
        echo '<style type="text/css"> #fullname {border-color: #f6c23e !important;} </style>';
        echo '<p class="p-3 text-warning">'.$warningfn.'</p>';
    }
    elseif (! $user->isValidFullname($fullname)){
        $infofn = 'Your name must be alphabetical characters';
        echo '<style type="text/css"> #fullname {border-color: #36b9cc !important;} </style>';
        echo '<p class="p-3 text-info">'.$infofn.'</p>';
    }   
    else {
        echo '<style type="text/css"> #fullname {border-color: #1cc88a !important;} </style>';
    }   
}

if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    //username validation
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    
    if (empty($_POST['username'])) {
        $warningun = "Please fill this field";
        echo '<style type="text/css"> #username {border-color: #f6c23e !important;} </style>';
        echo '<p class="p-3 text-warning">'.$warningun.'</p>';
    }
    elseif (! $user->isValidUsername($username)){
        $infoun = 'Your username must be at least 3 alphanumeric characters';
        echo '<style type="text/css"> #username {border-color: #36b9cc !important;} </style>';
        echo '<p class="p-3 text-info">'.$infoun.'</p>';
    }
    elseif (! $user->isUsernameAlreadyinUse($username)){
        $errorun = 'This username already in use';
        echo '<style type="text/css"> #username {border-color: #e74a3b !important;} </style>';
        echo '<p class="p-3 text-danger">'.$errorun.'</p>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<style type="text/css"> #username {border-color: #1cc88a !important;} </style>';
    }   
}

if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    //email validation
    $email = htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES);
    
    if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $warningm = "Please fill this field";
        echo '<style type="text/css"> #email {border-color: #f6c23e !important;} </style>';
        echo '<p class="p-3 text-warning">'.$warningm.'</p>';
    }
    elseif (! $user->isValidEmail($email)){
        $warningm = 'Please enter a valid email address';
        echo '<style type="text/css"> #email {border-color: #f6c23e !important;} </style>';
        echo '<p class="p-3 text-warning">'.$warningm.'</p>';
    }
    elseif (! $user->isEmailAlreadyinUse($email)){
        $errorm = 'This email already in use';
        echo '<style type="text/css"> #email {border-color: #e74a3b !important;} </style>';
        echo '<p class="p-3 text-danger">'.$errorm.'</p>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<style type="text/css"> #email {border-color: #1cc88a !important;} </style>';
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['password'])){

    $password= $_POST['password'];

    if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $warningpw = "Please fill this field";
        echo '<style type="text/css"> #password {border-color: #f6c23e !important;} </style>';
        echo '<p class="p-3 text-warning">'.$warningpw.'</p>';
    }
    elseif (! $user->isValidPassword($password)){
        $warningpw = 'Your password must be at least 6 characters long';
        echo '<style type="text/css"> #password {border-color: #f6c23e !important;} </style>';
        echo '<p class="p-3 text-warning">'.$warningpw.'</p>';      
    }
    else {
        echo '<style type="text/css"> #password {border-color: #1cc88a !important;} </style>';
    }   
}

if (isset($_POST['gender'])) {
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    if (!in_array($gender, ['Male','Female','Other'])) {
        $gender = 'Other';
    }
} else {
    $gender = 'Other';
}

//if form has been submitted process it
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){    

    //hash the password
    $hashedpassword = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

    //create the activasion code
    $activasion = md5(uniqid(rand(),true));

    try {

        //insert into database with a prepared statement
        $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO members (fullname,username,password,email,gender,active) VALUES (:fullname, :username, :password, :email, :gender, :active)');
        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':fullname' => $fullname,
            ':username' => $username,
            ':password' => $hashedpassword,
            ':email' => $email,
            ':gender' => $gender,
            ':active' => $activasion
        ));
        $id = $db->lastInsertId('memberID');

        //send email
        $to = $_POST['email'];
        $subject = "Confirm Your Account";
        $body = "<p>Thank you for registering on the demo site.</p>
        <p>Hello ".$fullname.", please click this link to activate your account: <a href='".DIR."activate.php?x=$id&y=$activasion'>".DIR."activate.php?x=$id&y=$activasion</a></p>";

        $mail = new Mail();
        $mail->setFrom(SITEEMAIL);
        $mail->addAddress($to);
        $mail->subject($subject);
        $mail->body($body);
        $mail->send();

        //redirect to index page
        header('Location: register.php?action=joined');
        exit;

    //else catch the exception and show the error.
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        $error[] = $e->getMessage();
    }
    
}
?>
```

Comment: Any specific reason you are doing so many ajax request - did you know you can send all this data in one request . Let me know if you need help with that

Comment: Can you please post you PHP code as well ? Thanks

Comment: The AJAX code can be optimized, but isn't inherently wrong. The problem is in your *registercontrol.php*

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I posted now.

Comment: @Martin I don't think so but I posted now maybe you can check.

Comment: There are a lot of things that need fixing in both PHP and ajax request. alot of things :)

Comment: Are you 100% certin that `$_POST['submit']` is set? I don't see it in the AJAX function, and you're not serializing a form element with this current AJAX code, so there is no actual *submit* function. Add `submit` as a nother data element and give it a string value or *1* or something. I have a lot more comments that I can post in an answer but first check if this is an actual issue please.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping a lot of? Well actually everthing works fine except this submit validations. But I'dont know the other problems if theyre exists.

Comment: @Martin At the beginning I serialized and after `.done` show the result. But I don't want to redirect or dynamically show the success of form submit with Ajax. I just want to check users if they are passing inputs empty or doing something wrong and show the errors or warnings. Then the php will take the process of success after validations completed.

Comment: Yes, but your problem is that your data is not inserting into the database, correct? If you have any other problems than that, the code you provided is not the issue.

Comment: @Martin I just wan't to fix my problem with that way but know I have new problem and want to fix with some helps.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping where you posted at? and thanks

Comment: @Martin I will try it, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One quick thing to notice is that you can optimize your AJAX function. There is absolutely no reason to make that many AJAX requests. You can send all of your data and do all of your success functionality in one AJAX request.

Another thing to notice is that your PHP code performs the database logic if the post variable `submit` exists. Right now you do not parse that through your AJAX function at all. You are not using a serialize method with a submit, but you're parsing very specific data, fetched manually by specifying each elements value.

What you could do, is parse `submit` as another data variable. I took the liberty to optimize your AJAX code with that idea in mind.

jQuery AJAX Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {       
    $('#submit').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var fullname = $("#fullname").val();
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        var submit = "1";
        
        $.ajax({
            url: 'registercontrol.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                fullname : fullname,
                username : username,
                email : email,
                password : password,
                submit : submit
            },
            success:function(response){                 
                $("#vfullname").html(response);
                $("#vusername").html(response);
                $("#vemail").html(response);
                $("#vpassword").html(response);  
            }
        });                     
    });
});
```

Now you will for sure have a submit `POST` variable that will enter your `if()` statement for the database inserts.

Another thing you could do is have more concrete checks on whether you should enter the statement that allows for database insertion or not. Right now it only revolves around the `POST` variable submit. No other logic. You might want to reconsider that. Make variables that start out as `FALSE` then when everything is okay with your validation checks, set them to true. Construct your database insertion´s `if()` statement around that instead, as that is way more relevant than whether a submit variable exists or not.

Another thing is that you're using an `md5()` hashing function for your password. This is highly insecure. Refer to [this article](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php).

You were also not concatenating the PHP variables properly on the line where you're telling the user to click the activation link. You concatenated your `super globals` just fine, but not the PHP variables.

With that said, there's nothing inherently wrong, other than what I pointed out.

Here is your PHP code:

```
<?php
if( isset( $_POST['fullname'] ) ) {
    //fullname validation
    $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];

    if( empty( $_POST['fullname'] ) ) {
        $warningfn = "Please fill this field";
        echo '<style type="text/css"> #fullname {border-color: #f6c23e !important;} </style>';
        echo '<p class="p-3 text-warning">'.$warningfn.'</p>';
    } else if( !$user->isValidFullname($fullname) ) {
        $infofn = 'Your name must be alphabetical characters';
        echo '<style type="text/css"> #fullname {border-color: #36b9cc !important;} </style>';
        echo '<p class="p-3 text-info">'.$infofn.'</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<style type="text/css"> #fullname {border-color: #1cc88a !important;} </style>';
    }   
}

if( isset( $_POST['username'] ) ) {
    //username validation
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    
    if( empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) {
        $warningun = "Please fill this field";
        echo '<style type="text/css"> #username {border-color: #f6c23e !important;} </style>';
        echo '<p class="p-3 text-warning">'.$warningun.'</p>';
    } else if( !$user->isValidUsername($username) ) {
        $infoun = 'Your username must be at least 3 alphanumeric characters';
        echo '<style type="text/css"> #username {border-color: #36b9cc !important;} </style>';
        echo '<p class="p-3 text-info">'.$infoun.'</p>';
    } else if ( !$user->isUsernameAlreadyinUse($username) ) {
        $errorun = 'This username already in use';
        echo '<style type="text/css"> #username {border-color: #e74a3b !important;} </style>';
        echo '<p class="p-3 text-danger">'.$errorun.'</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<style type="text/css"> #username {border-color: #1cc88a !important;} </style>';
    }   
}

if( isset( $_POST['email'] ) ) {
    //email validation
    $email = htmlspecialchars_decode( $_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES );
    
    if( empty( $_POST['email'] ) ) {
        $warningm = "Please fill this field";
        echo '<style type="text/css"> #email {border-color: #f6c23e !important;} </style>';
        echo '<p class="p-3 text-warning">'.$warningm.'</p>';
    } else if( !$user->isValidEmail($email) ) {
        $warningm = 'Please enter a valid email address';
        echo '<style type="text/css"> #email {border-color: #f6c23e !important;} </style>';
        echo '<p class="p-3 text-warning">'.$warningm.'</p>';
    } else if( !$user->isEmailAlreadyinUse($email) ) {
        $errorm = 'This email already in use';
        echo '<style type="text/css"> #email {border-color: #e74a3b !important;} </style>';
        echo '<p class="p-3 text-danger">'.$errorm.'</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<style type="text/css"> #email {border-color: #1cc88a !important;} </style>';
    }
}

if( isset( $_POST['password'] ) ) {
    $password= $_POST['password'];

    if( empty( $_POST['password'] ) ) {
        $warningpw = "Please fill this field";
        echo '<style type="text/css"> #password {border-color: #f6c23e !important;} </style>';
        echo '<p class="p-3 text-warning">'.$warningpw.'</p>';
    } else if ( !$user->isValidPassword($password) ) {
        $warningpw = 'Your password must be at least 6 characters long';
        echo '<style type="text/css"> #password {border-color: #f6c23e !important;} </style>';
        echo '<p class="p-3 text-warning">'.$warningpw.'</p>';      
    } else {
        echo '<style type="text/css"> #password {border-color: #1cc88a !important;} </style>';
    }   
}

if( isset( $_POST['gender'] ) ) {
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    if( !in_array($gender, ['Male','Female','Other']) ) {
        $gender = 'Other';
    }
} else {
    $gender = 'Other';
}

if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
    //hash the password
    $hashedpassword = password_hash( $password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT );

    //create the activasion code
    // this is highly insecure, see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php
    $activasion = md5( uniqid( rand(),true ) );

    try {
        //insert into database with a prepared statement
        $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO members (fullname,username,password,email,gender,active) VALUES (:fullname, :username, :password, :email, :gender, :active)');
        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':fullname' => $fullname,
            ':username' => $username,
            ':password' => $hashedpassword,
            ':email' => $email,
            ':gender' => $gender,
            ':active' => $activasion
        ));
        $id = $db->lastInsertId('memberID');

        //send email
        $to = $_POST['email'];
        $subject = "Confirm Your Account";
        $body = "<p>Thank you for registering on the demo site.</p>
                 <p>Hello ".$fullname.", please click this link to activate your account: <a href='".DIR."activate.php?x=".$id."&y=".$activasion."'>".DIR."activate.php?x=".$id."&y=".$activasion."</a></p>";

        $mail = new Mail();
        $mail->setFrom(SITEEMAIL);
        $mail->addAddress($to);
        $mail->subject($subject);
        $mail->body($body);
        $mail->send();

        //redirect to index page
        header('Location: register.php?action=joined');
        exit;

      //else catch the exception and show the error.
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        $error[] = $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

I will entrust that `$someVar->isValid()` refers to something that works as I have no other insight on that.

If you're having further errors outside of the database insertion now, the problem lies elsewhere. Either you're not following your table structure logic (typos, invalid data formats etc.)

Comment: It's working thank you and I will change hashing function in further. Also thanks for your Ajax optimization but your optimization showing each inputs validation inside of every div elements. I mean for example "Please fill this field" repeated 4 times in `#vusername` and also the others too.

Comment: Should be fixed now.

Comment: You will need to tell the error messages where they should go specifically. the *response* is equal to *html* which means that any *html* that is found inside the *registercontrol.php* page will be put into those elements. You will need to build a logic around that so that each error is displayed properly.

Comment: It seems I need more logical aprroach on this. I will try.